# Python syntax highlighting with the YAML(text editor)

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

I'm creating a simple Text editor in python using the Tkinter module. Recently I wanted to add the syntax highlighting feature to my text Editor. I refer some PDF and create this piece of code, but having some problems. Thanks for helping

These are the following error:

```
imtiyaz@Baka:~/Dropbox/NoteBooktest/test$ python3 high.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "high.py", line 48, in <module>
     hello(root,'yamlsh.yml')
  File "high.py", line 33, in __init__
     self.parse_syntax_file()
  File "high.py", line 13, in parse_syntax_file
     self.numbers_color = config['number']['color']
KeyError: 'number'
```

**Below is the code snippet**
code high.py

```
from tkinter import *
import yaml

class hello:
 def parse_syntax_file(self):
   with open(self.syntax_file,'r') as stream:
   try:
     config = yaml.load(stream)
   except yaml.YAMLError as error:
     print(error)
     return
   self.categories = config['categories']
   self.numbers_color = config['number']['color']
   self.strings_color = config['string']['color']
   self.configure_tag()

 def configure_tag(self):
   for category in self.categories.keys():
     self.color = self.categories['category']['color']
     self.text_waidget.tag_configure(category, foreground=self.color)
   self.text_widget.tag_configure("number", foreground=self.numbers_color)
   self.text_widget.tag_configure("string", foreground=self.strings_color)

 def __init__(self,master, syntax_file):
   self.master = master
   self.syntax_file = syntax_file
   self.text_widget =  Text(self.master)
   self.text_widget.pack()
   self.categories = None
   self.numbers_color = 'green'
   self.strings_color = 'red'
   self.disallow_pre_char = ["_","-",",","."]
   self.parse_syntax_file()
   self.text_widget.bind('<KeyRelease>',self.on_key_release)

 def on_key_release(self, event=None):
   self.highlight()

 def highlight(self, event=None):
   length = IntVar()
   for category in self.categories:
     matche = self.categories[category]['matche']
     for keyword in matche:
       start = 1.0
   self.text_widget.tag_add(category,idx,end)

root = Tk()
hello(root,'yamlsh.yml')
root.mainloop()`
```

**yamlsh.yml**

```
categories:
   Keywords:
    color:orange
    matche:[for, def, while, from, import, as, with, self]

    variables:
      color: red4
      matche: ['True', 'False', 'None']

    conditionals:
       color: green
       matche: [try, except, if, else, elif]

    functions:
       color: blue4
       matche: [int,str,dict,list,set,float]
    number:
       color: green;
    string:
       color: '#e1218b'
```

Thanks once again!

Comment: The code and YAML file as given should not yield the error you show. Make sure the YAML is correctly formatted (indentation may haven gotten wrong when pasting). Also, please create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it is obvious what you are asking about. This usually also helps you understanding the problem better. Right now, this looks more like a request for a code review than an inquiry about a specific problem.

Comment: @flyx as you said i have made changes in my .yml file but still having same bug

Comment: @AFTABKHAN your code indicates you are on Unix/Linux/macOS, what filesystem are you using that you cannot use the recommended `.yaml` extension (http://yaml.org/faq.html)?

Comment: @Anthon: the suffix is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Your yaml file has syntax errors, though that is not the problem. Once you fix the syntax errors you're first doing this:

```
config = yaml.load(stream)
```

`config` is now a mapping (dictionary) with a single key, 'categories', and that is a mapping with a single key 'Keywords'.

Later you do this:

```
self.numbers_color = config['number']['color']
```

`config` doesn't have the key 'number', so you get the key error. The only key `config` has is `categories`, and the only keyword under that is 'Keywords'.

If you're trying to get the value "green", you need to do something like this:

```
# get the 'categories' mapping
self.categories = config['categories']

# from 'categories', get the 'Keywords' mapping
self.keywords = self.categories['Keywords']

# from the 'Keywords' mapping, get the 'color' value for 'number'
self.numbers_color = self.keywords['number']['color']
```

Comment: sorry but still i didn't get it how can i check my .yaml file bugs